# date shown in database as 0000-00-00

Tags: php, mysql, unix-timestamp

Date shown in mysql database as 0000-00-00 when the data type is 'date', but when the data type is 'varchar(160)', it shown as 1454803200, now how I can get the correct date format as 'Monday 01 Feb 2016'? 
Here I have used php code 'INSERT INTO' to write into the table of the database.

Comment: Update your question with the *relevant* code.

Comment: You should at least try to find this answer yourself instead of just asking for the answer.  Try Googling for MySql date_format()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1454803200 looks to be a unix timestamp.  You can use MySQL functions to convert it or PHP functions to convert it if you want it in MySQL date format which is YYYY-MM-DD.

PHP date can convert it using the second argument of the function:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', 1454803200);
```

Within MySQL, you can use FROM_UNIXTIME() to convert it to a date format:

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(1454803200)
```